# gradlew.bat assembleRelease frozen if executed in Apache Tomcat (Windows Server)

Tags: android, tomcat, gradle, windows-server-2008

I'm developing a .war file that uses jsp with java files to execute some compilation commands like for example `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` to compile some APK android files.

I have a windows server 2008. If i test with eclipse launching tomcat with play button (launch on server), my app works perfectly. The problem is that if i start the tomcat server outside eclipse with `startup.bat` (tomcat/bin directory) then, when i deploy the .war and start the button which starts `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` command, the war gets blocked, like if it is waiting for something. It is very strange because if i launch this tomcat with eclipse, it works perfectly.

I tryes also to start startup.bat file using ***launch as administrator*** option from the context menu.

What considerations i should have to solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

After starting tomcat as a service it worked fine, i don't understand why, but if you start tomcat with startup.bat, it will not work